# ''there'' or ''it'' in a sentence

Tags: pronouns

> New York is a famous city.We will visit there.
>
> New York is a famous city. We will visit it.

Which pronoun is suitable? I prefer ''it'' as the word ''visit'' is a transitive verb in this sentence.

Comment: The first version should use a different verb: **We will go there**.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to remember is to know that after "**visit**" we place a subject - "**what/who?**"

So the correct sentence is the second one:

- New York is a famous city. We will visit it.